# Proof verification induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I am barely off and I don't know where my mistake is?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

This holds true for n = 1

We get $1 = \frac{1(2)}{2} \to  1$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

$k+(k+1) = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

$\frac{k(k+1)}{2} + (k+1) = \frac{k+1(k+2)}{2}$

$\frac{(k^2 + k +2k +2)}{2} = \frac{k+1(k+2)}{2}$

$k^2 + 3k + 2 = k^2 + 2k +k +2$

$k^2 + 3k + 2 = k^2 +3k +2$

This is my first time doing induction. This appears to be right? Should I also carry the summation notation all the way through? When am I supposed to drop it? Is there anything that should be stated at the end of proof? Any notation?

Comment: I'll note on first glance that there's very little explanation for your formulas. That's unusual, especially for an induction proof: a proof is supposed to explain your reasoning to people who have never seen it before. It's hard to understand exactly what you mean by your formulas if there's no explanation.

Comment: You should put the summation notation $\Sigma$ where it is appropriate, and  $$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\dfrac{\color{red}{n(n}+1)}2;$$ you "drop" the summation notation when you replace $\Sigma k$ with $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$

Comment: You're missing a pair of parentheses around $k+1$ in the  2nd and 3rd lines  of your computation And yes; id you have a sum, you have to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more correct way of explaining the inductive step, with a shorter computation, thanks to factorisation instead of systematically expanding:

Suppose that, for some $n\ge 1$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
We have to show that for the next integer,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}.$$

Now, from the inductive hypothesis, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k = \sum_{k=1}^n k +(n+1)= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)=(n+1)\biggl(\frac n2+1\biggr)=(n+1)\frac{n+2}2,$$
which proves the inductive step.

Answer (score 0):

There are wrong equations in your proof. For example, $k+(k+1)=\frac {(k+1)(k+2)} 2$ is not valid when $k=2$. Here is the correct argument:
for $n=1$: LHS is $1$ and RHS is $\frac {(1)(2)} 2=1$ so the result is true. Suppose the result holds for a particular value of $n$. Consider $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} k =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k +(n+1)=\frac {n(n+1)} 2 +(n+1)=(n+1) (1+\frac n 2)=(n+1) \frac {n+2} 2=\frac {(n+1)(n+2)} 2$ where we used the induction hypothesis for the second equality. This completes the induction argument.